# Cannot access my website

Tags: web-hosting

I am not very sure where is the problem, but it is following:

I have webhost http://dtech.id.lv

which I cannot access from both of my home PC's nor via browser nor via FTP.

It opens normaly if I use proxy or try to open this page on other then my home PC's

Is there any suggestions/methods I can try to detects where is problem and whats blocking connection?

I think problem appeared when I was messing with wordpress and .htaccess file which I deleted... (is there a way to reset webhosting without contacting anyone?)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you done a hard refresh on the page within your browser? CTRL + F5

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps:

1. Delete your Cookies
2. Delete your Temporary files
3. Exit Browser
4. Load Browser & Visit Site
5. If still blocked try a Ctrl+F5 to hard refresh the page.

If you still can't access the site then its a possible problem with your dns or the host has blocked your ip. Some web hosts will block you if you incorrectly enter the password when access their system via ssh or ftp X amount of times. So its possible that they have blocked you.

To rule out the chance of DNS simply turn off your router, and while the router is off do this on the PC (assuming its windows based) cmd (run as administrator) and do a ipconfig /flushdns

Then boot up the router, if that doesn't work then the chances are your host has blocked you and you will need to contact them as your IP will be blocked on their system.

Have your IP address ready for them, simply Google my ip will return this :P

Hope this helps, oh by the way forgot to mention the site was accessible on 2 ISPS my end and my phone ;)